# Making lots of buttons in tkinter with a loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create lots of buttons with tkinter, each with its own column and row, and would like to do so without writing out loads of code. I'm relatively new to programming so not sure how to do this. I cannot use the .grid() on the same line due to what I am doing later with the code. I have posted an example below. Thanks.

```
def Create():
    button1 = Button(root, text="button 1", command=1)
    button1.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=5)
    button2 = Button(root, text="button 2", command=2)
    button2.grid(row=7, column=1, pady=5)
    button3 = Button(root, text = "button 3", command=3)
    button3.grid(row=7, column=2, pady=5)
    button4 = Button(root, text = "button 4", command=4)
    button4.grid(row=8, column=0, pady=5)
    button5 = Button(root, text = "button 5", command=5)
    button5.grid(row=8, column=1, pady=5)
    button6 = Button(root, text = "button 6", command=6)
    button6.grid(row=8, column=2, pady=5)
    button7 = Button(root, text = "button 7", command=7)
    button7.grid(row=9, column=0, pady=5)
    button8 = Button(root,text = "button 8", command=8)
    button8.grid(row=9, column=1, pady=5)
    button9 = Button(root,text = "button 9", command=9)
    button9.grid(row=9, column=2, pady=5)
   
    global packing
    packing = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `Create`:

```
packing = []
buttonNumber = 1
for rows in range(7, 10):
    for cols in range(0, 3):
        b = tk.Button(root, text = "Button {}".format(buttonNumber), command = lambda i = buttonNumber: print(i))
        b.grid(row = rows, column = cols, pady = 5)
        packing.append(b)
        buttonNumber += 1
```

This will iterate through the rows and columns and will create a button which will print it's number when clicked (replace with the command you want to use). It then uses the row/column numbers to position the buttons and appends them to a list.

Comment: the value for row changes, it isn't  7 in all buttons.

Comment: @a121 Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't notice